# FullCalendar: Changing event start date and time format

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am pulling my Google Calendar feed to fullcalendar.  When I view the event details, the start time displays like this: Sun Feb 19 2012 15:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time).  I would prefer if it looked a little more 'normal' - maybe like this: Sunday, February 19, 2012 @ 3:00pm (EST).  I have read about formatdate, etc., but I still cannot get a grasp for what I actually need to do to change the format of the date and time.  I have been reading related topics in this forum, but at this point they are just confusing me more.  Thank you very much in advance for any help!  My fullcalendar code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    $.colorbox({
                        maxWidth:"800px", html:"<h1>"+calEvent.title+"</h1><h2>When</h2><p>"+calEvent.start+"</p><h2>Where</h2><p>"+calEvent.location+"</p><h2>"+calEvent.eventTime+"</h2><p>"+calEvent.description+"</p>"});
                  },
                  events:
                        {
                        url: 'my google calendar feed url'
                        }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the formatDate bit where it says "HH:mm" to the appropriate letters for what you're looking for [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/).

For what you're after (minus the EST bit which doesn't seem to be in the formatDate function) you're after something like this:

```
var eventTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, "dddd, MMMM yyyy @ h:sstt")+" to "+
                $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, "dddd, MMMM yyyy @ h:sstt");
```

Edit:
As I understand it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var eventTime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, "dddd, MMMM yyyy @ h:sstt")+" to "+
                        $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, "dddd, MMMM yyyy @ h:sstt");
        $.colorbox({
          maxWidth:"800px",
          html:"<h1>"+calEvent.title+"</h1>"+
             "<h2>When</h2>"+
             "<p>"+eventTime+"</p>"+
               "<h2>Where</h2>"+
               "<p>"+calEvent.location+"</p>"+
               "<p>"+calEvent.description+"</p>"});
        },
        events:
        {
            url: 'my google calendar feed url'
        }
     });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dolondro.  I edited my code above, because when that variable line is included, the calendar does not show up.  Even before trying to call the variable, the calendar does not show up if I add your code to define the variable under the "$(document).ready(function() {" line.  So, where exactly do I add the line for the variable?  Other than that, I think I understand the concept.